# Using accumarray to output a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, accumarray

MATLAB's [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is unbelievably powerful in many applications.  My issue, is that my `accumarray` function to apply on my inputs has three outputs, and `accumarray` can only handle scalar outputs.  For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
subs = [1;2;4;2;4;5];
vals = [1;1;1;2;5;1];
accumarray(subs, vals, [], @(x)[min(x),mean(x),max(x)],0)
```

and have `accumarray` return:

```
1.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000    1.0000
1.0000    1.5000         0    3.0000    1.0000
1.0000    2.0000         0    5.0000    1.0000
```

I suppose I could just run `accumarray` three times, but my function is slow, and running `accumarray` once would be vastly faster than running it three times.  Am I just hosed here?

Comment: Alternatively you can use [grpstats](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/repeatedmeasuresmodel.grpstats.html) from Statistics toollbox or you can use [regionprops](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) from Image Processing toolbox if you have a license.

Comment: @rahnema1, min/mean/max was just a concrete example to demonstrate my problem.  My actual function for accumarray is quite different from min/mean/max so grpstats doesn't help me.  I use regionprops daily, but I have no idea what you are describing.

Comment: you can use regionprops to find statistical properties of regions. usage: `stats = regionprops(subs, vals,'MaxIntensity','MeanIntensity','MinIntensity')`. As you siad that your actual function for accumarray is quite different from min/mean/max so regionprops also doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cheat make the anonymous function output a **cell array** instead of a single value. This way, `accumarray` will give you a cell array of matrices.  You can then concatenate all of the matrices to a single matrix when you're done.  Take note that your proposed anonymous function has the `min`, `max` and `mean` as a row vector but your expected result is a **column** vector.  Therefore I've transposed this inside your anonymous function.

The gotcha we have to take into account is the fill value.  The fill value you specified needs to be a scalar.  Therefore, you can cheat by leaving this out, but then your output will now contain empty matrices in the cell instead of the row of the result being filled with 0.  A way around this is to find all cells that are empty, replace them with a row of zeros, then piece it all together when you're done.  To figure out which rows of the `accumarray` output are going to be empty, you can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) combined with [`isempty`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) so we can see which elements in the result are empty.  A neater way to do this would be to first pre-allocate a matrix of `zeros` then only populate the rows that correspond to the non-empty locations in the output of `accumarray` to finish it off:

```
subs = [1;2;4;2;4;5];
vals = [1;1;1;2;5;1];
out = accumarray(subs, vals, [], @(x){[min(x),mean(x),max(x)].'});
ind_empty = cellfun('isempty', out);
out_final = zeros(3, numel(out));
out_final(:, ~ind_empty) = cat(2, out{:});
```

Take note of the use of [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) which is concatenating matrices together in a specified dimension.  Doing `out{:}` produces what is known as a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) so it is equivalent to taking each column of the `accumarray` output and putting them as individual arguments into `cat` so that we would eventually piece all of the columns together into a single matrix, but I'm slicing into the output in such a way where we're only populating those locations that were not empty.

With your test inputs, I match what you get:

```
>> out_final

out_final =

    1.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.5000         0    3.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    2.0000         0    5.0000    1.0000
```

---

However, if I can be honest - If you know for sure that you're going to only have three values to bin into `accumarray`, it may be faster to simply call it three times then concatenate everything when you're done.  I would argue that it's more readable and it makes it very clear what you're doing.  Doing it the way I did with the cell array above requires that you really know how MATLAB works.